# Ubuntu general user mkdir testing

Tags: scripts, users, mkdir, multiple-users

I have generic question about testing mkdir command,firstly I dont have root access, I am user `xyz` , I will create `mkdir dump && chmod 777 dump` , now is there a possibility in linux where i will login as user `xyz` and switch to some general test user and try to create mkdir /dump/asgenearluser, i want this directory to be created, with other dummygeneraluser

Comment: By default you can only switch to another user by entering the password of the other user or as root. Both would use the command `su`. See `man su`.